scrollTo specified position when entering page
When entering the page, I use window.scrollTo to scroll to a specified position, but it seems that the browser will scroll the page back to the top?
In a Vue3 project, I used window.scroll({top: 200, behavior: auto}) in the mounted lifecycle of home. vue; initially, the page would scroll to the top: 200 position, but after a moment, the page would automatically return to the top.
When I set behavior to smooth, this problem can be solved.
How to understand this

Please, provide a way to reproduce, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It doesn't make sense to discuss something that needs to be observed
